# How to get AdSchedule object with Google Ads API

Tags: php, ads, google-api-php-client

I am trying to get all Ad Schedules placed in Google Ads through the Google Ads API and obtain the start and end times (hour and minute) to compare it with some existing values and depending on whether they differ update accordingly.

Here is my code showing where I am iterating over returned Ad Schedules.

```
foreach($campaigns as $camp) {
        // Get restaurant and details
        $res = RestaurantsService::getRestaurantByName($camp->getName());
        $hours =$res->getHours()->dequeue();
        $start = explode("-",$hours)[0];
        $end = explode("-",$hours)[1];

        // Get current ad schedules as they are now
        $campaignAdSchedules = self::getCampaignAdSchedule($campaignCriterionService,$camp->getId());
        if ($campaignAdSchedules == null){
            $operations = [];

            $schedule = new AdSchedule();
            $schedule->setDayOfWeek(self::DAYS[date("N")-1]);
            $schedule->setStartHour((int)substr($start,0,2));
            $schedule->setStartMinute(MinuteOfHour::ZERO);
            $schedule->setEndHour((int)substr($end,0,2));
            $schedule->setEndMinute(MinuteOfHour::ZERO);

            $operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();

            $criterion = new CampaignCriterion();
            $criterion->setCampaignId($camp->getId());
            $criterion->setCriterion($schedule);

            $operation->setOperand($criterion);
            $operation->setOperator(Operator::ADD);
            $operations[] = $operation;

            $campaignCriterionService->mutate($operations);
        } else {
            foreach($campaignAdSchedules as $adSchedule){
                ---> $schedule = $adSchedule->getCriterion(); <---
            }
        }
    }
```

Here the line marked with arrows is the line I am having problems with.  The `getCriterion()` function returns a Criterion object which does not have the methods `getStartHour()` etc.  I have tried casting it but haven't found the correct way.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try check the instance:

```
$result = $campaignCriterionService->get($serviceSelector);
$campaignAdSchedules = $result->getEntries();
foreach ($campaignAdSchedules as $criterion) {
    $adSchedule =  $criterion->getCriterion();
    if ($adSchedule instanceof AdSchedule) {
        $adSchedule->getStartHour();
    }
}
```